# Building in PC a C struct for an embedded target

Tags: c, xml, parsing, embedded

I need to extract data from an XML and link it as a struct to a C embedded project.

The XML is unavailable in runtime. (no file system, file is too big, and security reasons). So I have to parse it and generate the struct on my PC pre-linkedge.

If I use binary data it won't necesarilly be in the same format as in the target (even with the a compiler from the same vendor, right?). Would you generate a c file to be compiled within the project? Is there an easier way?

```
struct myStruct s = generateMyStruct("file.xml");

s.generateCfile("convertedXml.c");
```

Comment: I suggest generating a C file to produce the binary data as a static array. If you create a binary data file, you face the issue of how to merge it into the embedded project. If the size of the data is an issue, it may be possible to use some type of compression on the data, but that would be an embedded runtime program to extract the data. Using something like [LZ77](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78#LZ77) is fairly simple.

Comment: another way would be to parse XML with python (for example) and use a *data/text template* to create the C struct from the data, then the C struct can be compiled with the rest C code as a normal piece of C code

Comment: Take a look to libxml2. Is a complete library to parse xml nodes. I use it with a little application that, as a pre compile option, translates xml to c files. Link [HERE](http://www.xmlsoft.org/)

Comment: As @NikosM.stated, paresing the XML using a high level language and generating the struct as C source code would be best. I use Python to create C source myself and really appreciate it. Not used XML lib su far, but I most other included libs are pretty easy to use, so I would expect the XML-lib for Python to be similar (note that, howevr, XML itself is not that simple as it has started). I certainly would give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Controlling Structure Layout

If you use the data types in `<stdint.h>` (e.g. `int32_t`, `uint8_t`) and define fields for every byte in your `struct` to keep types aligned with their sizes (e.g. 32-bit values should be 4-byte aligned, 16-bit values should be 2-byte aligned), then you should be okay and your structure's layout should match on both platforms.

For example, don't write a struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t a;
    uint32_t b;
} Foo;
```

because the compiler might magically stuff three bytes in between `a` and `b` so that `b` is a multiple of 4 bytes from the start of the structure. Instead, put those padding bytes in yourself:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t padding[3];
    uint32_t b;
} Foo;
```

Sometimes compilers have extensions for controlling packing and alignment. Make sure both compilers have these extensions before using them. Or just ignore the extensions and manually pad data as above.

## Generating C Initialization Code

Once you've written your code that creates the structure and fills it in with data parsed from XML, then you write your function `generateCfile` to generate your initialization file. It should be passed not only the output file or filename, but also a pointer to the initialized structure. (`s.generateCfile("convertedXml.c");` is actually C++ syntax, not C.)

```
void generateCfile(const struct Foo* s, const char* filename) {
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "w");

    fprintf(fp, "#include \"InitFoo.h\"\n\n");
    fprintf(fp, "const struct Foo kInitFoo = {\n");
    fprintf(fp, "    %u, { 0, 0, 0 }, %u\n", s->a, s->b);
    fprintf(fp, "};\n");

    fclose(fp);
}
```

By simply using standard initializer syntax, you don't have to worry about byte order differences between the platforms.

You should use the generated C file with a short header file declaring the constant structure:

```
#ifndef InitFoo_h
#define InitFoo_h

#include "Foo.h"

extern const struct Foo kInitFoo;

#endif
```

BTW, there's nothing saying that a code generator has to be written in the same language as the target's compiler. I frequently write code generators in Python that output C++.

```
# Remember to double braces that should be in the output.
TEMPLATE = '''
#include "InitFoo.h"

const struct Foo kInitFoo = {{
    {a:d}, {{ 0, 0, 0 }}, {b:d}
}};
'''

def generateCfile(foo, filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(TEMPLATE.format(**foo));

# test code
generateCfile({"a": 15, "b": 45}, "convertedXml.c")
```

Also, higher-level languages like Python tend to have easier to use XML or JSON parsers. YMMV.

For either code generator, and given a = 15 and b = 45 in the parsed structure, you should get this in `convertedXml.c`:

```
#include "InitFoo.h"

const struct Foo kInitFoo = {
    15, { 0, 0, 0 }, 45
};
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the detailed comment. That's exactly what I meant. I just wanted to know there's no easier way to do it, but with your demo code I actually see how easy it is.

One remark though:
You say I can rely on structure layout if following certain rules. I think you are wrong. Think of big & little endians, or double representations. None are standard. Even the 32bit alignment is not a must (only the order of members).

Comment: Mike, this is risky at best and broken at worst. Let alone, the padding array in the first exaple might vey well be aligned to a 32 or 64 bit boundary. This as it might be passed in a register to a function and so allows to bre read by a single 32bit read (or write). There is no guarantee the compilers for both platforms will behave the same; it may even depend on optimizations. This even more as we have no information about the two platforms; they might very well have different endian-ess..

Comment: Oh, and: C has `_Alignas()` (`alignas()` for C++ and if including `stdalign.h`; no need for platform-specific code. In general it is always very bad to directly pass the memory footprint of a datastructure between different platforms. Even if they use the same architecture, there might still be differences in optimizations or the OS. Some ARM CPUS for instance allow to use little or big endian for data.

Comment: @Olaf Funny thing is that the second part of my answer happens to not care a whit about compilers with broken padding. I didn't realize this until after I posted the answer. **Note that my answer does not involve transferring a binary pattern between platforms at all.**

Comment: There comes a point at which you have to abandon the pants-wetting fear that some compiler out there might go absurdly stuffing unneeded padding into everything, unlike the vast majority of compilers, while simultaneously ignoring that these oddball compilers likely do not support C11 or C++11, which introduced `_Alignas` and `alignas` respectively. Function-calling optimizations don't matter here because the structure (had we written it in binary form) would be passed by address to a `write` function, which would force the compiler to generate or preserve an in-memory copy.

Comment: The first part of your answer does imply this very well. Reagarding wetting my pants: I stopped this decades ago. This mostly because I am very well aware how to do my job; there simply is no need to fear if something is broken by design as I pretty well know about compiler optimizations, which might result in surprising layout - at a first glance. Modern compilers take so many aspects of the target architecture into account. You might rethink also, that I did not refer to passing this struct to a functions (or part of it, but that the compiler very well might optimize its layout in general.

Comment: For the second part, you did not suppose more than I and @NikosM for instance supposed already, so my comment on your's is obviously not about that. If the first part is just an introduction to the second, then there would be no reason why one would use manual padding anyway, There is absolutely no need for this; if there would be any need to somehow access the fields anonymously by their offset, `offsetof()` would be the standard way. And this can be very well defined as a macro for pre-C(++)11 compilers. But still no sense, as the data would be stored int he structs already at run-time.